# Trying to locate coordinates of the mouse when clicked, but always appears to be 0,0

Tags: java, graphics, mouselistener

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GameWindow extends JComponent implements ActionListener,     MouseListener{
private Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
private int scorenum = 0;
public  int mouseX, mouseY, 
            ranX = ((int)(Math.random()*5))*200,
            ranY = (((int)(Math.random()*4)+1))*200;
int[] cy = new int[] {200, 400, 600, 800}, cx= new int[] {0, 200, 400, 600, 800};
private JLabel score = new JLabel("score: " + scorenum, SwingConstants.CENTER);
private Color c1 = Color.RED, c2 = Color.BLUE;
public GameWindow() //constructor
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    score.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1015,200));
    add(score, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    score.setFont(new Font("Cooper Black", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    score.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    t.start();
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);
    setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();

    for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x ++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y ++) 
        {
            g.setColor(c1);
            g.fillOval(cx[x], cy[y], 200, 200);
        }
    }   

    g.setColor(c2);
    g.fillOval(ranX, ranY, 200, 200);
    g.fillOval(mouseX, mouseY, 200, 200);


}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Ellipse2D rancircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(ranX,ranY,200,200);
    if (rancircle.contains(mouseX, mouseY))
    {
        c2 = c1;
        ranX = ((int)(Math.random()*5))*200;
        ranY = (((int)(Math.random()*4)+1))*200;
    }  
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
    mouseX=m.getX();
    mouseY=m.getY();

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {

}


}
```

I am trying to make a game where players click on the circles that changed from c1 to c2, by clicking, the color goes back from c2 to c1. More and more circles are supposed to be changing from c1 to c2, and if the player isn't clicking faster than the rate at which color is changing(when all circles turn into c2), the player loses.

By drawing a circle with the coordinates mouseX, mouseY, I realized that I am not getting the mouseClicked coordinates properly, and I wonder what I did wrong.

Also, I am a complete beginner, so any advice on how to make this game would be very helpful.

I also do not know how I could make the changing of color increase in speed.

Please help me!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Doing `setFocusable(true);` and `this.requestFocusInWindow();` inside your `paintComponent` method is a bad idea. If you're trying to fix the focus related issues with `KeyListener` then you should avoid these kind of hacks and use the Key Bindings API instead, which solves this issue

Comment: So, I ran your code, and once I clicked the component the `mouseX` and `mouseY` values are updated

Comment: but I used mouseListener.

Comment: Then why do you need `setFocusable(true);` and `this.requestFocusInWindow();`? Doing this in the `paintComponent` could cause or sorts of unexpected side effects

Comment: could you show me how you got it to work? I'd really appreciate it. like I said I am a complete beginner.

Comment: i don't actually know, i did that because i had it in other programs i've written in class, so i thought i need it. would deleting them solve the problem?

Comment: It's about the only thing I removed from your original code

Answer (score 0):

So, I took your code, wrapped in a frame and after I click the component, the `mouseX` and `mouseY` values will change

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GameWindow());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GameWindow extends JComponent implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

        private Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
        private int scorenum = 0;
        public int mouseX, mouseY,
                ranX = ((int) (Math.random() * 5)) * 200,
                ranY = (((int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1)) * 200;
        int[] cy = new int[]{200, 400, 600, 800}, cx = new int[]{0, 200, 400, 600, 800};
        private JLabel score = new JLabel("score: " + scorenum, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        private Color c1 = Color.RED, c2 = Color.BLUE;

        public GameWindow() //constructor
        {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            score.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1015, 200));
            add(score, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            score.setFont(new Font("Cooper Black", Font.PLAIN, 50));
            score.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            t.start();
            addMouseListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 800);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponents(g);
            setFocusable(true);
            this.requestFocusInWindow();

            for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++) {
                    g.setColor(c1);
                    g.fillOval(cx[x], cy[y], 200, 200);
                }
            }

            g.setColor(c2);
            g.fillOval(ranX, ranY, 200, 200);
            g.fillOval(mouseX, mouseY, 200, 200);

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Ellipse2D rancircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(ranX, ranY, 200, 200);
            System.out.println(mouseX + "x" + mouseY);
            if (rancircle.contains(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                c2 = c1;
                ranX = ((int) (Math.random() * 5)) * 200;
                ranY = (((int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1)) * 200;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
            mouseX = m.getX();
            mouseY = m.getY();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it still isn't changing after I run your code, at least on my end.

Comment: The example post works fine for - not sure what else to add

Comment: @RachelLai I've not run the above examples on two different computers without issue